# Snowpipe support for loading data from GCS (google cloud storage) external stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(An interesting question posed by a user that bears posting on this forum)

---

We are trying to ingest data from GCS and want to use Snowpipe REST API for doing so but we are unsuccessful at this point. Could you guys let us know whether Snowpipe is supported for GCS (both for continuous loading as well as triggering through REST endpoints). Also if it's not supported can we know the timeline when Snowpipe support will be there for GCS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The following answer was originally provided by a Snowflake Technical Account Manager)

---

The snowpipe is not supported for GCS as of now. It is planned for future. For timeline, we need to get in touch with Snowflake support.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/3-27-Release-Notes-June-4-2019

While not Snowpipe, you can accomplish automated loading of files in GCP Storage Buckets by leveraging some of the native GCP features, I was able to do so with the following three steps:

1, Create a GCP PubSub Topic - instructions: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin

2, Create a GCP "Cloud Function" that issues the copy into command, using this article as a reference:
https://medium.com/@phil.goerdt/automating-your-snowflake-database-cloning-with-gcp-b30a84f04b6d

further instructions: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-console

3, Create a GCP "Notification" on your storage bucket, this is the "trigger" that will now be called when files arrive or are updated on your GCS storage bucket.

```
gsutil notification create -t projects/gcpProjectNameHere/topics/gcpTopicNameHere -e OBJECT_FINALIZE -f json -p parentBucketFolder/childBucketFolder/ gs://gcpBucketNameHere
```

It's not nearly as cool as Snowpipe, but it should work, good luck!